# arg$ \frac {z_1 - z_3} {z_2- z_4} = \pi/2 $ or $- \pi /2$.

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers

I was reading Complex Algebra. I read some concepts about a rhombus whose co-ordinates are anticlockwisly $\;z_1 , z_ 2 , z_ 3 , z_4 $  .
Then I understood that the following statements are true.

1. $z_1 - z_2 + z_3 - z_4 =0$
2. arg$  \frac {z_1 - z_3} {z_2- z_4} = \pi/2 \;\text{  or}\;  - \pi /2$.
3. arg$  \frac {z_1 - z_2} {z_3 - z_4} = \pi$.

Can anyone please correct me If I have gone wrong anywhere.

Comment: Yea..Rhombus........